# In a case statement, what is mutually exclusive values?

Tags: c#, .net

Lately I'm intent on dive into C# and coming from Java background.
When I come `switch-case` topic to review, I see the following term.

> Because C# 6 supports only the constant pattern and doesn't allow the
>   repetition of constant values, case labels **define mutually exclusive
>   values**, and only one pattern can match the match expression. As a
>   result, the order in which case statements appear is unimportant.
>
> In C# 7.0, however, because other patterns are supported, **case
>   labels need not define mutually exclusive values**, and multiple
>   patterns can match the match expression. Because only the statements
>   in the first switch section that contains the matching pattern are
>   executed, the order in which case statements appear is now important.
>   If C# detects a switch section whose case statement or statements are
>   equivalent to or are subsets of previous statements, it generates a
>   compiler error, CS8120, "The switch case has already been handled by a
>   previous case." - [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#case-labels)

What does it mean *mutually exclusive values* in this regard? Can you exemplify for both, mutually and non-mutually exclusive values?

Comment: Did you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch It might answer your question.

Comment: @blackforest-tom I forgot to add its source. Thanks.

Comment: If you scroll down to "The case statement and the when clause", there are good examples. Basically constant values will be mutually exclusive, if they're different. They will never be non-mutually exclusive. If you go for the when clause, you can have non-mutually exclusive values (via inheritance or conditions!)

Comment: Think about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#type-pattern and how an item can match more then one pattern

Comment: # to note, https://web.archive.org/web/20190827120008/https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/pattern-matching-switch-statements

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HWyPfl)):

```
object o = "text";

switch (o)
{
    case string s:
        break;
    case "text":
        break;
}
```

`o` is both a string (causing the first case block to match) and it equals `"text"` (causing the second case block to match). Thus, the two case labels are not mutually exclusive.

Since the second one is a subset of the first one (every `"text"` is a string), you get the compiler error mentioned in your question ("The switch case has already been handled by a previous case."). You get this error because the second case block is unreachable code, so the compiler deduces that this is probably not what you intended.

Note that swapping the two labels *would* work without a compile-time error:

```
switch (o)
{
    case "text":
        break;
    case string s:
        break;
}
```

In that case, the first case block handles the case where `o == "text"`, and the second one covers all other strings. They are still not mutually exclusive, but you have the more specific one first, which is OK.